# gtk-config команда не найдена

Tags: gtk3

`-bash: gtk-config:` команда не найдена

Запускаю в `MSYS2`. В чем проблема?

Команда компиляции

```
$ gcc -mwindows -std=c89 *.c *.h ./action/*.c -o a $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 sqlite3)
```

Comment: Что вы предприняли, что бы установить местонахождение `gtk-config`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
> предупреждение: mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3-3.22.1-1 не устарел -- переустанавливается
> разрешение зависимостей...
> проверка конфликтов...
>
> Пакеты (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3-3.22.1-1
>
> Будет установлено:  73,29 MiB
> Изменение размера:   0,00 MiB
>
> :: Приступить к установке? [Y/n]
> ```

Comment: И что надо ответить - Y или n?

Comment: gtk3 уже установлен по этому пути C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0 находится по этому пути